# Vue.js Axios calling current URL I'm on not the one I'm calling

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I'm trying to call API to fetch data from it, it doesn't display anything. When I check console logs to check for errors I see that Axios calls 'https://niklavric.com/posnetek/https;//niklavric.com/api/posnetki/obrtna-zbornica-50-let' instead of 'https://niklavric.com/api/posnetek/obrtna-zbornica-50-let'. I'm using Laravel and Vue js.

```
<script>
  export default {
    data(){
        return{
            posnetekData: '',
            posnetekOpis: ''
        }
    },
    created:function(){
        var path = window.location.pathname;
        var splitPath = path.split('/')[2];
        var fullPathName = splitPath.split('%20').join(' ');

        axios.get("https://niklavric.com/api/posnetki/"+fullPathName).then((response) => {
            if(response.data != null){
                this.posnetekData = response.data.data[0];

                this.posnetekOpis = response.data.data[0].opisPosnetka.split(";");

            }else{
                this.posnetekData = 'Video not found.';
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is it necessary to define the request path dynamically depending on window.location instead of just writing explicitly in axios.get();

Comment: did you set the base url of axios as "https://niklavric.com/posnetek/" somewhere else in your project?

Comment: Are you sure that's the code that's requesting that URL? The error message has a semi-colon in the `https;//` section, which looks likely to be a simple typo. Failing that, what do you get if you console log `fullPathName`?

Comment: I didn't set no base URL

Comment: I fixed that typo but it still shows the error

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention, console log shows error "TypeError: e.data.data is undefined", but e is not declared anywhere in the code.

Comment: @Liondalan Please, update the question according to your latest fixes. If there's an error, it should be listed because gives important information on what happens. I'm sure `e` stands for `response` here because you're running minified app. It means that there's no `data: [...]` in the response. Currently only you can debug the app and the response in particular.